# Copy exe file to Qt build directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, exe, qmake

I am trying to write a Qt application that will use `QProcess` to call `ffmpeg.exe` to convert media files. I cannot figure out the best way to make sure that the `ffmpeg.exe` file gets copied from my development directory to the build directory so that the built (and later deployed) application will have access to it.

I have seen information about using the `INSTALLS` parameter in my .pro file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13168287) but the qmake docs say:

> Note that qmake will skip files that are executable.

with all of the above said, how should one go about making sure that the exe file I want to use for `QProcess` ends up in the build directory (ready to be deployed later)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QMAKE_POST_LINK` to execute a copy command when the application is built. Just put this in your .pro file :

```
win32:{

    file_pathes += "\"$$PWD/Path/To/Files/ffmpeg.exe\""

    CONFIG(release, debug|release):{
        destination_pathes += $$OUT_PWD/release/
        destination_pathes += Path/To/Deploy/Directory
    }
    else:CONFIG(debug, debug|release):{
        destination_pathes += $$OUT_PWD/debug/
    }

    for(file_path,file_pathes){
        file_path ~= s,/,\\,g
        for(dest_path,destination_pathes){
            dest_path ~= s,/,\\,g
            QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(xcopy $${file_path} $${dest_path} /I /Y $$escape_expand(\n\t))
         }
    }
}
```

You should add the paths for the files that you want to be copied to `file_pathes` variable and the paths to the destination directories to `destination_pathes` variable. Then all files would be copied to all the destinations when the application is built.

Here `ffmpeg.exe` gets copied to application build and deploy directories in release mode and to build directory in debug mode.

Comment: This looks great, I haven't had a chance to try it out, but once I verify that it works I will mark this as the answer. Does this only work on Windows?

Comment: On other platforms you should use the platform specific commands. For example on Linux you should use `cp` to copy a file like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745076/how-do-i-stop-qt-creator-placing-my-executable-in-a-debug-subdirectory/27745759#27745759

Comment: You can make it conditional in the .pro file based on the platform. For example use `win32:{...}` for Windows, `linux:{...}` for Linux or `mac:{...}` for Mac Os X.